# syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'a'

Tags: c++

I am attempting to build a dll on Visual Studio 2019 (for using in Unity later) from a c++ sdk project that was previously compiled with gcc. I am getting some syntax errors while compiling and for the following function:

```
static inline uint8_t MyFunction(const uint64_t *__restrict__ a, const uint64_t *__restrict__ b)
```

I get this error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2146   syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'a'
```

Any clue on how to fix this? And in general on how to solve other errors stemming from changing compilers like this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`__restrict__` is specific to gcc and clang.  The MSVC equivalent is `__restrict`.

There is no 'general way' to resolve differences between compilers.  You have to deal with them on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: Thanks! The equivalency works! It's a bummer that's how the differences are dealt with though.